# Mapreduce Job to implement a HiveQL statement

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, bigdata

I have a question. How to do Mapreduce Job to implement a HiveQL statement. for example we have a table with column names color, width and some other columns. Suppose if i want to select color in hive i can give select color from tablename;. In the same way what is the code for getting color in Mapreduce.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Thrift server. You can connect to hive through JDBC. All you need is to include the hive-jdbc jar in your classpath.

However is this advisable? Well that i am not really sure. This is a very bad design pattern if you are doing it in the mapper as no. of mappers is determined by data size.

The same can be achieved as multiple inputs into MR job.

But then i do not know that much about your use case. So thrift will be the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

For converting hive queries to mapreduce jobs, ysmart is the best option

http://ysmart.cse.ohio-state.edu/

Either ysmart can be downloaded or online version can be used.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [companion code](https://github.com/adamjshook/mapreducepatterns/tree/master/MRDP/src/main/java/mrdp/ch5) `Chapter 5 - Join Patterns` from the `MapReduce Design Patterns` book. In the join pattern the fields are extracted in the mapper and emitted.